# Turn off buffering

Tags: python, linux, bash, buffering

Where is the buffer in this following ... and how do I turn it off?

I am writing out to stdout in a python program like so:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

There is some buffering going on here:

```
tail -f data.txt | grep -e APL | python -u Interpret.py
```

I tried the following to shake off possible buffering ... with no luck:

- as above using the -u flag with python invocation
- calling sys.stdout.flush() after each sys.stdout.write() call
  ... all of these create a buffered stream with python waiting something like a minute to print out the first few lines.
- used the following modified command:

  stdbuf -o0 tail -f data.txt | stdbuf -o0 -i0 grep -e APL | stdbuf -i0 -o0 python -u Interpret.py

To benchmark my expectations, I tried:

```
tail -f data.txt | grep -e APL
```

This produces a steady flow of lines ... it surely is not as buffered as the python command.

So, how do I turn off buffering?
ANSWER: It turns out there is buffering on both ends of the pipe.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/183066)

Comment: I wish it were a duplicate. None of the solutions mentioned there work in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem, I believe is in `grep` buffering its output. It is doing that when you pipe `tail -f | grep ... | some_other_prog`. To get `grep` to flush once per line, use the `--line-buffered` option:

```
% tail -f data.txt | grep -e APL --line-buffered | test.py
APL

APL

APL
```

where `test.py` is:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

(Tested on linux, gnome-terminal.)

Comment: Yes Yes !!! This is the answer ! Though to be precise, I had to use While True: line=sys.stdin.readline() ... your suggestion as it stands didn't work for me. So, I think it was the buffering on both ends of the pipe that made it hard. ... Thanks.

Comment: Hm, interesting! What version of Python, and what OS are you using? (My version works for Python2.7+Ubuntu+gnome-terminal).

Comment: Good point. With Python 3, your method works. With python 2.6, it doesn't.

Answer (score 12):

`file.readlines()` and `for line in file` have internal buffering which is not affected by `-u` option (see [-u option note](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html?highlight=buffering#cmdoption-u)). Use

```
while True:
   l=sys.stdin.readline()
   sys.stdout.write(l)
```

instead.

By the way, `sys.stdout` is line-buffered by default if it points to terminal and `sys.stderr` is unbuffered (see [stdio buffering](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)).

Comment: Replace first line with ````l=None; while l!='':```` so loop terminates on end-of-input?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your for loop. It will wait for EOF before continuing on. You can fix it with a code like this.

```
while True:
    try:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break 

    if not line:
        break

    print line,
```

Try this out.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)` and make sure `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` is set in your environment.

Comment: nope! That is not it ... should have mentioned that I had already tried it. Also, it seems like PYTHOHNUNBUFFERED is equivalent to setting the -u flag http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED

Comment: BTW, with python 3, the above line causes the error: ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O