# Taking input from sys.stdin, non-blocking

Tags: python, input

I'm working on a bot for a competition that receives its input through `sys.stdin` and uses Python's `print()` for output. I have the following:

```
import sys

def main():
    while True:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts) > 0:
            # do stuff
```

The problem is that the input comes in through a stream and using the above, blocks me from printing anything back until the stream is closed. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: [maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416586/turn-off-buffering) a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)

Comment: Non-blocking on stdin either doesn't work or doesn't work very reliably. Are you allowed to use threading/multiprocessing? Cause that should work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By turning blocking off you can only read a character at a time. So, there is no way to get `readline()` to work in a non-blocking context. I assume you just want to read key presses to control the robot.

I have had no luck using `select.select()` on Linux and created a way with tweaking `termios` settings. So, this is Linux specific but works for me:

```
import atexit, termios
import sys, os
import time


old_settings=None

def init_any_key():
   global old_settings
   old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
   new_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
   new_settings[3] = new_settings[3] & ~(termios.ECHO | termios.ICANON) # lflags
   new_settings[6][termios.VMIN] = 0  # cc
   new_settings[6][termios.VTIME] = 0 # cc
   termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, new_settings)


@atexit.register
def term_any_key():
   global old_settings
   if old_settings:
      termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)


def any_key():
   ch_set = []
   ch = os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 1)
   while ch is not None and len(ch) > 0:
      ch_set.append( ord(ch[0]) )
      ch = os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 1)
   return ch_set


init_any_key()
while True:
   key = any_key()
   if key is not None:
      print(key)
   else:
      time.sleep(0.1)
```

A better Windows or cross-platform answer is here: [Non-blocking console input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/python-nonblocking-console-input)

Comment: Note that this *also* makes the terminal "non-echoing": keypresses are not shown. Here is another elegant way of achieving the same: http://ballingt.com/nonblocking-stdin-in-python-3/

Comment: When remote debugging with VS Code in my RPi, the read character was an int, not str. Adding the following made the code work also from remote:

      if type(ch[0]) is int:
         ch_set.append(ch[0])
      else:
         ch_set.append( ord(ch[0]))

Comment: If you want unicode characters to be correctly interpreted use sys.stdin.read(1) instead of os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 1)

Answer (score 11):

You can use selectors for handle I/O multiplexing:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html

Try this out:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys
import fcntl
import os
import selectors

# set sys.stdin non-blocking
orig_fl = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin, fcntl.F_SETFL, orig_fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

# function to be called when enter is pressed
def got_keyboard_data(stdin):
    print('Keyboard input: {}'.format(stdin.read()))

# register event
m_selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()
m_selector.register(sys.stdin, selectors.EVENT_READ, got_keyboard_data)

while True:
    sys.stdout.write('Type something and hit enter: ')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    for k, mask in m_selector.select():
        callback = k.data
        callback(k.fileobj)
```

The above code will hold on the line

```
for k, mask in m_selector.select():
```

until a registered event occurs, returning a selector_key instance (k) and a mask of monitored events.

In the above example we registered only one event (*Enter key press*):

```
m_selector.register(sys.stdin, selectors.EVENT_READ, got_keyboard_data)
```

The selector key instance is defined as follows:

```
abstractmethod register(fileobj, events, data=None)
```

Therefore, the register method sets `k.data` as our callback function `got_keyboard_data`, and calls it when the *Enter* key is pressed:

```
callback = k.data
callback(k.fileobj)
```

A more complete example (and hopefully more useful) would be to multiplex stdin data from user with incoming connections from network:

```
import selectors
import socket
import sys
import os
import fcntl

m_selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()

# set sys.stdin non-blocking
def set_input_nonblocking():
    orig_fl = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin, fcntl.F_SETFL, orig_fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

def create_socket(port, max_conn):
    server_addr = ('localhost', port)
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.setblocking(False)
    server.bind(server_addr)
    server.listen(max_conn)
    return server

def read(conn, mask):
    global GO_ON
    client_address = conn.getpeername()
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print('Got {} from {}'.format(data, client_address))
    if not data:
         GO_ON = False

def accept(sock, mask):
    new_conn, addr = sock.accept()
    new_conn.setblocking(False)
    print('Accepting connection from {}'.format(addr))
    m_selector.register(new_conn, selectors.EVENT_READ, read)

def quit():
    global GO_ON
    print('Exiting...')
    GO_ON = False


def from_keyboard(arg1, arg2):
    line = arg1.read()
    if line == 'quit\n':
        quit()
    else:
        print('User input: {}'.format(line))

GO_ON = True
set_input_nonblocking()

# listen to port 10000, at most 10 connections
server = create_socket(10000, 10)

m_selector.register(server, selectors.EVENT_READ, accept)
m_selector.register(sys.stdin, selectors.EVENT_READ, from_keyboard)

while GO_ON:
    sys.stdout.write('>>> ')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    for k, mask in m_selector.select():
        callback = k.data
        callback(k.fileobj, mask)


# unregister events
m_selector.unregister(sys.stdin)

# close connection
server.shutdown()
server.close()

#  close select
m_selector.close()
```

You can test using two terminals.
first terminal:

```
$ python3 test.py 
>>> bla
```

open another terminal and run:

```
 $ nc localhost 10000
 hey!
```

back to the first

```
>>> qwerqwer
```

Result (seen on the main terminal):

```
$ python3 test.py 
>>> bla
User input: bla

>>> Accepting connection from ('127.0.0.1', 39598)
>>> Got b'hey!\n' from ('127.0.0.1', 39598)
>>> qwerqwer     
User input: qwerqwer

>>>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation with your post, so that it is clear and easy to understand for future visitors

Comment: Note that since python 3.5, you can simply do [`os.set_blocking(sys.stdin.fileno(), False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?#os.set_blocking) to make stdin non-blocking

Answer (score 7):

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get a character from the keyboard.  If Block is True wait for input,
# else return any available character or throw an exception if none is
# available.  Ctrl+C isn't handled and continues to generate the usual
# SIGINT signal, but special keys like the arrows return the expected 
# escape sequences.
#
# This requires:
#
#    import sys, select
#
# This was tested using python 2.7 on Mac OS X.  It will work on any
# Linux system, but will likely fail on Windows due to select/stdin
# limitations.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

def get_char(block = True):
    if block or select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0) == ([sys.stdin], [], []):
        return sys.stdin.read(1)
    raise error('NoChar')
```

Comment: I believe I tried this on Linux a while back and I don't think it worked. However, on the Mac I am on right now, it definitely does not work. Whether block is true or false, it still blocks. Additionally, the user has to press enter to release the "flood" of chars that gets built up. Maybe try to set input mode to raw (`tty.setraw()`) but then you have to set it to cooked mode after that.

Comment: This was a bit strange for me with `read(1)`, but with `stdin.readline()` it worked perfectly.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but then I realised he doesn't necessarily have a tty. He talks about an input stream.  If he knows he has a tty he could indeed use `tty.setraw(sys.stdin)` but that won't work if the competition executes his program via an ssh session (for instance).

Answer (score 3):

This is a posix solution, similar to [the answer by swdev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32382950/4298200).

As they stated, you have to play with `termios.VMIN` and `termios.VTIME` to catch more than one char without requiring user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Trying to only use raw mode will be a problem as special keys like arrows can mess next keypress.

Here we use `tty.setcbreak()` or `tty.setraw()` as a shortcut, but they have [short internals](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/tty.py).

```
import termios
import tty
import sys
import select

def get_enter_key():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    orig_fl = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setcbreak(fd)  # use tty.setraw() instead to catch ^C also
        mode = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        CC = 6
        mode[CC][termios.VMIN] = 0
        mode[CC][termios.VTIME] = 0
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, mode)
        keypress, _, _ = select.select([fd], [], [])
        if keypress:
            return sys.stdin.read(4095)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, orig_fl)

try:
    while True:
        print(get_enter_key())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('exiting')
    sys.exit()
```

note that there are two potential timeouts you could add here:

- one is adding last parameter to [`select.select()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select)
- another is [playing with VMIN and VTIME](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/termios.3.en.html#Canonical_and_noncanonical_mode)

Comment: can you explain why you read so many bytes? `sys.stdin.read(4095)`

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote this snippet, but has to be only about consuming all input in case user pasted some (long) text.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest `nobreak`? If'n you are willing to use curses.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.nodelay

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get read of a stream with either

```
sys.stdin.read(1)
```

to read utf-8 decoded chars or:

```
sys.stdin.buffer.read(1)
```

to read raw chars.

I would do this if I wanted to get raw data from the stdin and do something with it in a timely manner, without reading a newline or filling up the internal buffer first.  This is suitable for running programs remotely via ssh where tty is not available, see:

```
ssh me@host '/usr/bin/python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.isatty())"'
```

There are some other things to think about to make programs work as expected in this scenario.  You need to flush the output when you're done to avoid buffering delays, and it could be easy to assume a program hasn't read the input, when you've simply not flushed the output.

```
stdout.write("my data")
stdout.flush()
```

But usually it's not the input reading that's the problem but that the terminal (or program) supplying the input stream is not handing it over when you expect, or perhaps it's not reading your output when you expect.  If you have a tty to start with (see ssh check above) you can put it into raw mode with the tty module.

```
import sys
import termios
import tty

old = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
tty.setraw(sys.stdin)
c = None
try:
    c = sys.stdin.read(1)[0]
finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
print(c)
```

... if using Mac/Linux.  If using Windows you could use msvcrt.getch().

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `set_blocking` now. This works on Linux and can probably be adapted to work on other systems by changing how the fd is created.

```
class CooperativeInterrupt:

    def __init__(self):
        self.fd = open('/dev/stdin', 'rb')
        os.set_blocking(self.fd.fileno(), False)

    def __del__(self):
        if self.fd is not None:
            self.fd.close()

    def has_interrupt(self):
        data = self.fd.read()
        if data is None:
            return False
        if len(data) == 0:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt()  # Stdin closed (e.g. CTRL+D).
        return True


coi = CooperativeInterrupt()
for i in range(10000000000000):
    if coi.has_interrupt():
        print(i)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score -7):

Use a generator - thankfully `sys.stdin` is already a generator!

A generator enables you to work on an infinite stream. Always when you call it, it returns the next element. In order to build a generator you need the `yield` keyword.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line

    if a_certain_situation_happens:
        break
```

Do not forget to place a `break` statement into the loop if a certain, wished situation happens.

You can find more information about generators on:

- http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/index.html
- http://linuxgazette.net/100/pramode.html

Comment: Aren't there other factors at play, though? Such as if the stream is line- or block-buffered?

Comment: sys.stdin is already a generator, so you can just do `for line in sys.stdin: ...` or use the newer `fileinput` module. neither are non-blocking though.