# How to check string length while I am typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, if I type "S" the length should count to 1, and at the end when I finish the word "Stack" the length must be given 5.

Comment: More information. *Where* are you typing the string? How is python involved with that?

Comment: In python you can use:
len(string)

But not sure where are you typing and how are you passing value to python

Comment: I am trying to make a password program. Suppose you type a password for a Wi-Fi network, then after 8 characters the password button is enabled. I want to do that.

Comment: How are you reading the input? If you're using `input()` then it won't work.

Comment: Depends on what you need exactly, [python - Taking input from sys.stdin, non-blocking - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791621/taking-input-from-sys-stdin-non-blocking) may work. Or search for a TUI library. Otherwise just prompt the user for a different password in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **len()** to get the length of string.

```
    >>> s=input('Enter a string- ')
    Enter a string- stack
    >>> len(s)
    5
```

Then you can use a loop to check the length every time.

```
x='yes'
while True:
   my_string=input('Enter a string- ')
   length=len(my_string)
   x=input(f'It is of length {length}....Enter yes/no to continue...  ').lower()
   if x =='no':
     break
   elif x not in ('yes','no'):
     print('\nPlease enter only yes or no (yes/no)....\n')

print('exited')
```