# Clean input stream before calling input()

Tags: python

I'm experiencing a problem with input(). I've a program like:

```py
while condition:
    do_stuff()
value = input("Insert data >> ")
```

If I write `something` while the loop is executing, when `condition` becomes False and  input() is executed, `Insert data >> something` is printed on the CLI.

How can I prevent `something` from being printed? Is there a method to flush the input stream before calling input()?

Comment: This is called typeahead and provided (usually) by the underlying readine.  Does reading from stdin before the input call fix it?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to disable this? It's usually thought of as a feature for users who know what's coming next.

Comment: I tried to sys.stdin.read() and readline() before, but without success.
Yes, I want to cancel all the data accidentally inserted before the input() statement!

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to do a non-blocking read before calling `input()`, to consume everything in the buffer and throw it away. But you _will_ annoy users by doing this -- it breaks any ability to feed your program's stdin from a file or a heredoc or anything else that provides all the input up-front.

Comment: Thanks. If I make a read before input() it will consume also the input()'s message...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791621/taking-input-from-sys-stdin-non-blocking may be relevant.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks.