# Subprocess popen: Why do all writes happen at once in child process?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, popen

I have two scripts, one controlling the other and communicating to it via stdin. The parent script:

```
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(['python','read_from_stdin.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for i in range(0,10):
    p.stdin.write(str(i))
    p.stdin.write('\r\n') # \n is not sufficient on Windows
    p.stdin.flush()
    print i
    time.sleep(1)

p.stdin.close()
```

The child script (called 'read_from_stdin.py'):

```
import sys
import datetime

with open(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S') + '.txt','w') as f:

    for line in sys.stdin:
        f.write(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat() + ' ' + line)
```

In the file that's created by the child script all the inputs have the same timestamp, despite being written a second apart by the parent script, and despite the use for flush().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [the read-ahead bug in Python 2](https://bugs.python.org/issue3907): `for line in sys.stdin:` doesn't yield anything until its internal buffer is full. Use `for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):`, to workaround it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As per Karoly Horvath's comment below, **it's not the case that it waits for  for EOF, but there's buffering**. The different child script below does work as expected.

I found this question on the subject: [How do you read from stdin in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)

A fair way down in the answers is:

> The answer proposed by others:
>
> ```
> for line in sys.stdin:
>   print line
> ```
>
> is very simple and pythonic, but it must be noted that **the script will**
>   **wait until EOF before starting to iterate on the lines of input**.

This child script behaves as expected:

```
import sys
import datetime

with open(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S') + '.txt','w') as f:

    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    while line:
        f.write(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat() + ' ' + line)
        line = sys.stdin.readline()

    f.write('Finished')
```

Comment: Just wanted to post :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416586/turn-off-buffering It *doesn't* wait for EOF, but there's *buffering*. Please update your answer.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: it is correct that it doesn't wait for EOF but the question you've linked is unrelated (the fix `grep --line-buffered` won't work here -- OP already calls `p.stdin.flush()`). The issue is the read-ahead bug in Python 2 with `for line in sys.stdin`. The workaround is: `for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, '')`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath : I saw it. The solution works but there is no indication in the answer about the actual cause (bug in CPython 2)

Comment: You saw it now. And yes, it's a bug.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: If you are suggesting that I haven't seen it before your comment or haven't understood it then you are wrong. Look at [my answers in the `subprocess` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4279+%5Bsubprocess%5D). If you want me to be notified about your comments then use @ username syntax.